# ST_Multi returning GeometryCollection in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, geometrycollection

I am working in Postgres 9.6. I have a table called `builtup_areas`:

```
                                          Table "public.builtup_areas"
    Column    |             Type             | Collation | Nullable |                    Default                     
--------------+------------------------------+-----------+----------+------------------------------------------------
 ogc_fid      | integer                      |           | not null | nextval('builtup_areas_ogc_fid_seq'::regclass)
 objectid     | bigint                       |           |          | 
 wkb_geometry | geometry(MultiPolygon,27700) |           |          |
```

And a table called `local_authorities`:

```
                                           Table "public.local_authorities"
     Column     |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |                      Default                       
----------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------------------------
 ogc_fid        | integer                  |           | not null | nextval('local_authorities_ogc_fid_seq'::regclass)
 wkb_geometry   | geometry(Geometry,27700) |           |          | 
 canonical_name | character varying        |           |          |
```

I am trying to create a new table that contains the `ST_Difference` between the local authority's boundary, and the built-up areas, for each local authority. I have made a new table to hold this, with a MultiPolygon column:

```
CREATE TABLE las_without_buas(gid serial primary key, geom geometry(MultiPolygon,27700), county varchar(1000));
```

This is my code:

```
INSERT INTO las_without_buas(county, geom) 
  SELECT 
    county, 
    ST_Multi(ST_Difference(la.geom, bua.wkb_geometry)) AS geom 
  FROM
    (SELECT canonical_name AS county, wkb_geometry AS geom FROM local_authorities) la, 
  builtup_areas bua;
```

But when I run it, I get this error:

```
ERROR:  Geometry type (GeometryCollection) does not match column type (MultiPolygon)
```

I don't understand why it's trying to insert a GeometryCollection when I've specifically used `ST_Multi` to return a MultiPolygon. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that it is already ST_Difference that is returning geometry collections. They can't be expressed with any multigeometry. You may get for example empty results as `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY` http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Difference.html.

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Multi(
(
    ST_Difference(
            ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(50 100, 50 200)'),
            ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(50 100, 50 200)')
        )
    )));
```

Add a filter that passes only polygons and multipolygons from ST_Difference for ST_Multi.

Comment: Thanks! Could you give me a hint as to how I might add a filter? (Google is failing me, but just need a hint!)

Comment: https://postgis.net/docs/GeometryType.html `where GeometryType(....) in ('POLYGON','MULTIPOLYGON)`.